# How to copy and paste data from another spreadsheet with condition and specific range with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy and paste the values from another spreadsheet with a condition on source spreadsheet if column D is not null and Column E is null, then copy and paste the data. I have a lot of data about 12k+ rows and 50+ columns. I already made my own code, but it got some timeout error while accessing the target sheet because it takes too long to paste the data/ values.

```
function myfunction() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheetByName('');
  var datas = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow() - 1, 6).getValues(); //get the values until column 6
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('');

  var arr = [];
  for (let i in datas) {
    if (datas[i][3] != '' && datas[i][4] == '') {
     arr.push(datas[i]);
    }
  }
  target.getRange("A2:G").clearContent();
  target.getRange(2, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
  target.getRange(2, 1, target.getLastRow() - 1, target.getLastColumn()).sort({ column: 5, ascending: false });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data because I tested this with almost 8k rows and 10 columns but it was executed in 8 seconds.

Comment: Also if possible try to use the target sheet id if possible instead of activespreadsheet.

Comment: Sorry, i forget to adding the number of columns that i have. I have 50+ Columns in my real data

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
function myfunction() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheetByName('');
  var datas = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow() - 1, 6).getValues(); //get the values until column 6
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('');

  var arr = datas.filter(e=>e[3]&&!e[4]).sort((a,b)=>b[4]-a[4]);
  var range = target.getRange("A2:G");
  range.clearContent();
  range.offset(0,0,arr.length,arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I already try your code, but still get the timeout error

Comment: @AskingBob do you really need the data in the sheet? how about as a csv in your drive?

Comment: Yeah, i need the data in the sheet

Comment: @AskingBob you might need to sign up for a paid Google Account so you can get more script time.

Comment: Your code actually works. I just found the problem for my case that the apps script execution was interrupted by the formula in my Google Spreadsheet

Comment: @AskingBob Ah, great to hear! How fast?

Comment: Actually, I forget the time. But its enough to move the data without any kind of timeout problem

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myfunction() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheetByName('');
  var datas = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow() - 1, 6).getValues(); 
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('');
  var arr = datas.map((r,i) => {
    if(r[3] != '' && r[4] == '') {
      return r;
    }
  });
  target.getRange("A2:G" + target.getLastRow()).clearContent();
  target.getRange(2, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
  target.getRange(2, 1, target.getLastRow() - 1, target.getLastColumn()).sort({ column: 5, ascending: false });
}
```

Comment: Hello @Cooper, I just try your code. I got some trouble that it stop when there is a row in the middle of data that doesn't fit with the condition

Answer (score 0):

Class SpreadsheetApp methods are very slow. Try using the Advanced Sheets Service or the Sheets API (you will need to use Class UrlFetchApp).